# How to check if an element has proper URL and not just #

Tags: jquery

How to check if an element has a proper URl like http or https and not just #

For example

```
1. <a href="http://example.com">Has a URL</a>
2. <a href="https://example.com">Has a URL</a>
3. <a href="#">Has no proper URL</a>
4. <a href="http://example.com/#my-div">Has a URL and also a hash</a>
```

I tried with contain selector and it does not work like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($('.nav-res-navigation li a').is('[href*="#"]')){
        $('.nav-res-navigation li a').css('background', 'red');
    };
    });
```

**I just want to check if the** `href` **has # (*no URL*) or not**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector to match them directly:

```js
$('.nav-res-navigation li a[href="#"]').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav-res-navigation">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">Has a URL</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">Has a URL</a>
    <a href="#">Has no proper URL</a>
    <a href="http://example.com/#my-div">Has a URL and also a hash</a>
    <a href="#">Has no proper URL</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> How I can make it in if/else statement like if $('.nav-res-navigation li a[href="#"]') is true, addClass to another element

To do that check the `length` property of the selector:

```
if ($('.nav-res-navigation li a[href="#"]').length) {
  $('.some-other-element').addClass('foo');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How I can make it in if/else statement like if $('.nav-res-navigation li a[href="#"]') is true, addClass to another element.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value of attribute `href`, then check if the string matches:

```
var url = $('.nav-res-navigation li a').attr('href');

if (url === '#') { ...
```